# How to view all directories with auditing enabled on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, security, filesystems, windows-audit-mode

A while back I enabled file auditing on a few folders on my Windows 7 machine, but I have forgotten which folders I enabled it on.  Is there any way to view a list of all the folders which have at least one auditing permission turned on?

Answer (score 0):

The audit log appears in the Security log in Event Viewer. To enable this feature:

- Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Administrative Tools.
- Double-click Local Security Policy
- In the left pane, double-click Local Policies to expand it
- In the left pane, click Audit Policy to display the individual policy
  settings in the right pane.
- Double-click Audit object access.
- To audit successful access of specified files, folders and printers, 
  select the Success check box.
- To audit unsuccessful access to these objects, select the Failure 
  check box.
- To enable auditing of both, select both check boxes.
- Click OK.

Comment: This is not what I am asking.  I know how to enable auditing; I am asking if there is a way to show folders that have auditing permissions already enabled on them.

Comment: Yes,if you follow above steps it will show all the logs for auditted files.